# Python packages and their license in the binary program

Tags: python, licensing

I am writing a program in Python that currently uses several different packages, mainly BSD licenses, e.g. Pandas, NumPy, etc. The finished program is distributed in the form of an .exe file. My question is whether I should inform somewhere in the program that such packages were used and under what licenses?

I haven't found a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: `requirements.txt` file is for this or documentation.  But if it is a standalone `exe`, then nothing is needed...

Comment: so if I understand correctly, I am not obliged to inform in the "about the program" tab or anywhere in the program that the program uses such packages?

Comment: it is good practice to credit content providers, but in terms of the `exe` file being able to run without dependencies (i.e. the technical coding part), there would be no issue since an `exe` is a standalone file.

Comment: Depends on the licenses. Check the licenses of your dependencies regarding what you are required to do. GPL for example means you have to make the code available.

Comment: You write "mainly BSD licenses", but for this site here we would like to see a complete list of all licenses used. There are also different BSD licenses (4-clause, 3-clause, 2-clause, 0-BSD), you should clearly state, which one. And lastly, please explain what is your difficulty in understanding the [license language](https://opensource.org/license/bsd-2-clause/) "*Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.*"

Comment: The language of the license is understandable to me, it's more about how I should do it. Should I, for example, include it in the program instructions (this is the documentation provided with the program) information about the packages and copy its license to each of them, or just list what was used under which license and attach the appropriate license. I would appreciate an example.

Comment: We will need the complete list of licenses to provide a comprehensive answer. If you are just looking for examples, then type *about:license* in Firefox or *chrome://credits/* in Google Chrome, or for Adobe Acrobat Reader look at http://www.adobe.com/go/thirdparty .

Comment: The question about BSD "Redistributions in binary form" has been Asked and Answered here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/clarification-of-bsds-second-clause-binary-must-reproduce-copyright-notice

Answer (score 3):

Of course, if you package a file and provide packages that are covered by a given license, you MUST provide copyright notices if that license requires them (e.g., MIT, BSD, GNU GPL, and others like that).

In practice, many developers may avoid this, but if you want to be completely correct, you should include all the information.

The exception to this rule is when the user downloads the packages themselves (via `requirements.txt file`, but if you package to an EXE, I doubt this applies to you.

For Python, you can use the [`pip-licenses`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/) command, but it lists all the packages you have installed, not those required by `requirements.txt` or others, so if you want to use this tool, create a virtual environment.

I recommend this combination, but remember that you should adapt it to yourself.

`pip-licenses --with-notice-file --with-license-file --output-file ThirdPartyNotices.html --format html --no-license-path`

You can change the format to another, like plain text or CSV. [Here,](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/#option-format) you can read the details.

*pip-licenses must be installed beforehand*

**THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have another question: do I have to list all the packages I used? For example the tkintermapview package has the following dependencies: geocoder, pyperclip, pillow, pywin32, customtkinter, requests, some of them have further dependencies, should I list all of them in this case?

Comment: If the authors of the package you are using didn't do this, you should do it this way.

This may occur with packages that are only provided in source code. As I said, then the package is listed by name and there is no need to provide information in tkintermapview, because tkintermapview requires you to have these packages. You package EVERYTHING in binary, so you have to.

Remember that when you install tkintermapview you are installing all the dependencies, so the pip-licenses tool should also include the licenses for all the dependencies.